# create pdf in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pdf-generation

I have to generate a huge PDF file that contains data from 200 strings and 4 tables. Is there any way to visually create the PDF, and then fill the data from my strings in the right place? If not, what would be the best way to do this? For now I tried drawInRect: method.

Thanks for any suggestion
Radu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look to 
[NSPDFImageRep](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPDFImageRep_Class/index.html&ei=FGX-Tca6MIzz-ga2s93bAw&usg=AFQjCNFrSYR_AsDSc0bhg9HdjJDNWcyuhw&sig2=poE1zTu6BZD4TEl8MNv7LA)
[CGPDFContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html)

Here's some sample code

```
NSMutableData* pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef) pdfData);
CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height);
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate( consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);

CGDataConsumerRelease( consumer );

NSGraphicsContext* newGC = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:pdfContext flipped:YES];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:newGC];
```

Then you can draw your pdf pages calling

```
CGPDFContextBeginPage( pdfContext, NULL );
/* draw here */
CGPDFContextEndPage( pdfContext );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I don't really understand how it uses a template, but I will let you know if it is the good direction.